# The usage of constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, memory, constructor

constructors are used for initializing fields(attributes) after the creation of objects, right?
and the memory allocates no space to class code before the instantiation. so there is nothing to be initialized.

so how the code below prints **num** with value 12, while there is no constructor function?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class My_Class{
    public:
    int num =12;
};
int main(){
    My_Class Hello;
    cout<<Hello.num;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++11 you can provide an initializing value in the declaration for non-static member variables, like you do with `int num = 12`. This `num(12)` is implicitly added to an initialization list of a default constructor. In other words, it would be the same as if you have written:

```cpp
My_Class() : num(12) {}
```

**N.B.** Even though you haven't explicitly added default constructor, it is implicitly added by compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`My_Class` has an [implicitly-defined default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-defined_default_constructor), that sets `num == 12` as specified by the [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)